# Why I am geeting white blank screen while launching the iOS Cordova App?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am getting white blank screen while launching iOS Cordova app randomly. I am getting following logs on Xcode.

```
 2018-03-28 19:13:32.425 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.3 is starting.
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.426 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.446 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] initializing SVBMobileSharedSpace sharedManager
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.488 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] Using UIWebView
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.489 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.059962ms
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.491 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.289964ms
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.491 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.058055ms
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.504 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] [CDVTimer][file] 12.962937ms
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.514 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 9.267926ms
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.514 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] [CDVTimer][localstorage] 0.261068ms
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.514 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 24.904013ms
    2018-03-28 19:13:32.619 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] Resetting plugins due to page load.
    2018-03-28 19:13:33.184 Mobile_iOSApp[36112:484827] Finished load of: file:///Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F6A408EE-EAD1-450A-A8A8-C0D098B86262/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AECF4BF9-77B6-4A31-B3D3-086DF11A6215/Mobile_iOSApp.app/www/index.html
```

I am not getting this error every time.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Cordova 8.0.0. Upgrade your Cordova framework to version 8.0.0 and replace the Cordova.js file in your www folder.

Comment: Can you provide the source for this info? I think I have the same issue.